# Packaging LAMP with ssl despite it being a crypto

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, lamp

I've come across this statement on [the apache web site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/win_compiling.html).

> The OpenSSL library is cryptographic
>   software. The country in which you
>   currently reside may have restrictions
>   on the import, possession, use, and/or
>   re-export to another country, of
>   encryption software. BEFORE using any
>   encryption software, please check your
>   country's laws, regulations and
>   policies concerning the import,
>   possession, or use, and re-export of
>   encryption software, to see if this is
>   permitted. See
>   http:// www.wassenaar.org/  for more
>   information.

So how come most lamp flavors come with ssl included? We're thinking to roll a lamp version to include some specific additions, so understanding the significance of this would help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter for your company's lawyers.